# android - animation doesn't work the second time

Tags: android

I have a button which need to fade in. But it works only the first time. It doesn't work the second time.

Here is my code.

```
    final TextView doctorInfoView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.doctorInfo);
    final TextView specialtyView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.specialty);

    final ImageButton deleteDoctor = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.deleteDoctor);
    final Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in_animate);
    final ImageButton editDoctor = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.editDoctor);
    final RelativeLayout mainRowLayout = (RelativeLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.doctorListInfoView);
    final LinearLayout rowLayout = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.doctorInfoLayout);
    final LinearLayout editButtonLayout = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.editButtonLayout);
    final LinearLayout deleteButtonLayout = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButtonLayout);
    rowLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isClicked) {
                editDoctor.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
                editDoctor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                deleteDoctor.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
                deleteDoctor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mainRowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                doctorInfoView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                specialtyView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                editButtonLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#16aea3"));
                deleteButtonLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#16aea3"));
                isClicked = false;
            } else {
                editDoctor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                deleteDoctor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                                mainRowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f4"));
                doctorInfoView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                specialtyView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0d9e9f"));
                editButtonLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f4"));
                deleteButtonLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f4"));
                isClicked = true;
            }
        }

    });
```

Here is fade_in_animate.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <alpha 
           android:fromAlpha="0.0"
            android:toAlpha="1.0" 
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
            android:duration="500"/>
    </set>
```

I'd appreciated about any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solve this would be to set the animation to null

```
editDoctor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editDoctor.setAnimation(null);
```

EDIT: You forgot to set it to infinite

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Here is the xml

```
android:repeatCount="-1"
android:repeatMode="repeat"
```

Here is the full [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

---

EDIT 2: I didn't see that you are setting the alpha. My bad. This should work! You don't need to repeat it. This will work with the method of setting the animation to `null`.

```
editDoctor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editDoctor.setAnimation(null);
editDoctor.setAlpha(.0f);
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work. It behaves same. It works only the first time. It doesn't work when I click several times.

Comment: It is not supposed to repeat. so I modified your code like this, android:repeatCount="0". It's a button. I don't want it to blink. I just want it to  fade in when a user clicks a background layout and disappear when a user clicks it again.  The button fades in the first time when I click the background layout, but it just pops up the second time instead of fading in.   Your code still doesn't work. thanks anyway.